# java simple login system user delete account file system exception

Tags: java, file, authentication, ioexception

Hello I am trying to implement a simple user login system for an assignment, and this means being able to delete your account. On startup, the user login system program looks through a directory for folders, each folder name representing a different user and each user folder containing an "INFO.txt" file which says their username and password. For some reason when I try to delete files in the user directory I get the following error from the eclipse console:

```
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: users\george\INFO.txt: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.delete(Unknown Source)
at java.nio.file.Files.delete(Unknown Source)
at MessagingApp.deleteAccount(MessagingApp.java:414)
at MessagingApp.mainMenu(MessagingApp.java:333)
at MessagingApp.login(MessagingApp.java:237)
at MessagingApp.start(MessagingApp.java:180)
at MessagingApp.<init>(MessagingApp.java:30)
at Main.main(Main.java:5)
java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException: users\george
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.delete(Unknown Source)
at java.nio.file.Files.delete(Unknown Source)
at MessagingApp.deleteAccount(MessagingApp.java:424)
at MessagingApp.mainMenu(MessagingApp.java:333)
at MessagingApp.login(MessagingApp.java:237)
at MessagingApp.start(MessagingApp.java:180)
at MessagingApp.<init>(MessagingApp.java:30)
at Main.main(Main.java:5)
```

here is my class containing my delete account method and the loading method which is called on startup:

```
public class MessagingApp {

private Scanner scanner;
private ArrayList<User> userList; //All users currently registered
private User currentUser; //The user currently logged in

public MessagingApp() {

    scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    userList = new ArrayList<User>();

    try {
        this.load();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    this.start();

}

/**
 * loads all user information currently stored 
 * @throws IOException 
 */
private void load() throws IOException {

    Path users = Paths.get("users");
    File usersDir = users.toFile();
    String[] entries = usersDir.list(); //Each string in this list represents a user folder

    if(entries!=null) {

        for(String s: entries) {

            Path thisUser = Paths.get("users/"+s);
            File thisUserDir = thisUser.toFile();
            String[] userFiles = thisUserDir.list();

            for(String file: userFiles) {

                if( file.equals("INFO.txt") ) {

                    try {

                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("users/"+s+"/INFO.txt"));
                        String info = reader.readLine();
                        String[] credentials = info.split(":");
                        userList.add(new User(credentials[0],credentials[1]));
                        credentials=null;
                        info = null;
                        reader=null;

                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }

                }

            }

        }

    }

}

private void deleteAccount() {

    String choice;

    System.out.println("Are you sure you want to delete your account?");

    while(true) {

        choice = scanner.nextLine();

        if((choice.equals("y"))||(choice.equals("n"))) {
            break;
        }

        System.err.println("Invalid selection");

    }

    if( choice.equals("n") ) {
        mainMenu();
    }

    if( choice.equals("y") ) {

        Path userPath = Paths.get("users/"+currentUser.getUsername());
        File userDir = userPath.toFile();
        String[] userFiles = userDir.list();

        if(userFiles!=null) {

            for(String s: userFiles) {

                Path userFilePath = Paths.get("users/"+currentUser.getUsername()+"/"+s);

                try {
                    Files.delete(userFilePath);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        }

        try {
            Files.delete(userPath);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        userList.remove(currentUser);
        currentUser=null;

    }

}
```

If anyone has any pointers as to where I am going wrong it would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Comment: anyone have any ideas? bump

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you have the *"users\george\INFO.txt"* opened in some application. For example in Notepad or in your IDE. Therefore, it locks it from deleting by your app.

My advice to you is to try this particular feature separately. For example, I have tried the below snippet and it works in my environment.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;


public class MessagingApp {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        deleteAccount();
    }

    private static void deleteAccount() {
            Path userFilePath = Paths.get("Z:/users/test/INFO.txt");
            try {
                Files.delete(userFilePath);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

This is basically the same as you do, however very simplified. Please, create a separate class and a test file on your file system and test it. If it works you can be sure that the code most probably is Ok and the issue is in the environment. Again, my guess that you have it opened somewhere else. Hope it helps.